# Installing Google 2 step Authentication causes SSH to not connect

Tags: 12.04, ssh, authentication, google

I am following the instructions here

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-two-factor-authentication

After making the changes listed to

```
/etc/pam.d/sshd and /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and then restarting SSH, I cannot connect with another terminal to SSH, I get

```
connection refused
```

I have to then comment out the changes and restart SSH to get it back working.

Is there something I am doing wrong or is there a bug?